# Angular 8 & Firebase, observing data after adding a new item

Tags: angular, typescript

What I have right now:

Two Models:

User.ts

and

Company.ts

I need User to have only one company tied to it, therefore when the user registers, it automatically registers a new company on the **firestore** table.

This diagram explains it a little better of what I'm doing right now:

[image]

This is how I initiate the procedure (inside the user registration method from register.component.ts):

```
this.companyService.addCompany(this.companies, this.user);
```

And this is how the company.service.ts works:

```
export class CompanyService  {
  companiesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Company>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private userService: UserService) {
    this.companiesCollection = this.afs.collection('companies',
      ref => ref.orderBy('company_name', 'asc'));
  }

  addCompany(company: Company, user: User) {
    this.companiesCollection.add(company).then(docRef => {
      user.company_id = docRef.id;
      user.uid = localStorage.getItem('userUID');
      this.userService.addUser(user);
    });
  }
}
```

I would think it's better to do something along the lines of:

```
addCompany(company: Company): Observable<Company> {
  return this.companiescollection.add(company); // THIS CODE DOESNT WORK
}
```

And then use the subscription method on register.component.ts, such as:

```
this.companyService.addCompany(this.companies).subscribe(companyRef => { this.user.company_id = companyRef.id; this.userService.add(this.user); });
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I know it's not the answer you are looking for, and hopefully I can respond in a bit with something that tackles it as soon as I have a few more minutes, but have you considered using a firebase cloud function to handle this transaction?

Comment: @JohnGallego I would love to, I'm unsure of how it works. I'll look into it, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just have to convert that promise into an Observable, right? If you try:

```
import {from} from 'rxjs';
...
addCompany(company: Company): Observable<Company> {
  return from(this.companiescollection.add(company));
}
```

Shouldn't that do it for you?

Comment: Awesome, didn't know how to convert the promise. Thanks for that.